# What "bad list v: No such file or directory at -/usr/libdata/per15/OpenBSD/Pkg_Add.pm line 1115" means?

Tags: software-installation, perl, openbsd

I recently installed OpenBSD on an old laptop from 2005 and I am trying to install nano and then xfce4 and then a few other programs, but every time I try to use pkg_add, I get the message:

```
Fatal error: bad list v: No such file or directory at -/usr/libdata/per15/OpenBSD/Pkg_Add.pm line 1115
```

Answer (score 0):

I had run into the same issue while following blogged instructions. It turned out, the command I was using was incorrectly formatted. My mistake, `pkg_add -lv software` the tags after - should have been an uppercase I and a lower case v instead of a lowercase L and a lowercase v. This occurred through a misinterpretation with the fonts used on the instructions used.

`pkg_add -Iv software`

After correcting this typo, everything went well. Hopefully, this also corrects your issue and good luck.

Comment: Even now, in the plain text without the code markers, it looks much like a lower case L. Ah, font.